# Adding passes to Apple Wallet from Files folder on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, wallet

I have an iPhone 6s which I mistakenly "upgraded" to iOS 13 about six months ago.  While the phone is still functional, many things are not working.  Including downloading passes from e-mail links.  I downloaded the passes on my Macbook and copied them into an iCloud folder.  The passes are now on my phone in the shared folder but I can't find any way to get them into Wallet.  Any suggestions will be eagerly seized on and tested.  FWIW I have an iPad but the Wallet app isn't visible as far as I can tell.

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: Why not click the link given in the email and open it in Browser ? it might open in Safari. also try using messages. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204003 please give it a read too @tony

Comment: I apologize for my incomplete problem description.  iOS 13 broke e-mail and a few other items on my phone.  But I just tried the usual method (click a link in mail, opens the ticket download window, click "Add to Apple Wallet") and it worked.  No idea why, but I have long believed that posting questions like this and running diagnostics on the device sometimes scares it into behaving.  Thanks for your reply.  (Those who want to learn more about this should search for my handle tonylima in the Apple Communities.)

Comment: No worries, it happens to a lot of us.. Please post an answer :) see the [tour] also. You can be a regular here too!